# Deploying WebRoles to pre-existing VMs

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

We have developed and tested our webroles in our Free trial Azure cloud.

We now have to deploy the webroles to Company A Azure cloud. Company A is open to creating IIS VMs for our deployment but will not share username/pwds with us to publish our Webroles to their cloud.

This should be a pretty common scenario, would like to hear from folks who have solved it in their deployments.

How do we publish web roles to a pre-existing VM?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how Web Roles work. A Web Role (along with any other defined roles) is essentially a bundle of code, startup scripts, binaries, etc. that are needed on the VM. The VM itself is stateless: It's started up as a fresh (up to date) copy of Windows Server, and your code is executed. Anything needing install is done via your startup scripts.

You cannot push a Web Role independently to an existing Virtual Machine. You'd need to take your actual code project (e.g. asp.net) and publish *that* to a pre-existing VM, without any of the Web Role scaffolding. How you do that would be up to you (and the folks who are managing these VMs).

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a confusion with different concepts.

From what I understand you have already deployed your cloud service and associated web roles to a trial azure subscription. You were able to do that because you are the admin of the subscription. If you need to deploy the same set of roles and the cloud service to one of your customers azure subscription they will need to setup your account as a co-admin so you can follow the same deployment procedure you did with your trial subscription. They don't need to give you a user/pass pair. They just need to give your LiveID or appropriate credentials a temporary co-admin permission to do the deployment on their behalf. They can do this in the azure management portal.